# How can software track [1] how many subscribers to subreddits, [2] if subreddit is private, [3] if submissions are restricted?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Super User post: [How can software track [1] how many subscribers to subreddits, [2] if subreddit is private, [3] if submissions are restricted?](https://superuser.com/questions/1613368/how-can-software-track-1-how-many-subscribers-to-subreddits-2-if-subreddit)

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question.

First off, apology! What does "focuses on one problem only"? My post is pretty snippy already.  I asked about three characteristics, but do you want me to post separate questions for each?

Answer (score 5):

> First off, apology! What does "focuses on one problem only"?

You asked 3 separate questions. You should focus on a single question.

> I asked about three characteristics, but do you want me to post separate questions for each

The underlying question you are actually seeking isn’t within scope.  We are not a script writing service.  We can help you figure it out but only if you provide what you have attempted.

> But how do I command Excel to check these?

You are basically asking us for the Excel function.

> I don't even know if Excel can't do this. If it can't, how do I accomplish?

This is an **extremely** confusing sentence.  Additionally, questions about Reddit, is specifically out of scope on Super User. So you must first determine if the information you want to collect can be collected.  If you don’t know if it’s possible then that is specifically out of scope at Super User

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - It's up to the author of the question to tell us what they "mean", if I am left guessing what they mean, the question should be treated as "unclear".  It seems new users take having their question closed as a negative thing, it's only negative if they never clarify their question or address the reason it was closed.  To be clear it's only negative in the sense they don't get their question answered.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 apology!!! i fixed question 3 now. clear?

Comment: @Ineverattendeduniversity. - Your question now is asking for a software recommendation which is specifically out of scope.  When the question is within scope it will receive enough votes to be reopened.  Please don’t ask for this to happen via a comment (I will specifically ignore such a request and flag such a comment as unnecessary)